# Is it possible to have more than one screen in Parallels?

Tags: multiple-monitors, virtual-machine, parallels

I use Parallels 10 on Yosemite. My hardware has one screen or two screens, depending on if I use the laptop and/or an external screen in combination. However, Parallels only recognises one screen:

[image: Windows 7 Display settings showing one screen]

(Here in the Windows 7 Display settings.)

**Is it possible for Parallels to use two screens, such that each screen is on one OSX space?**

Much like I swipe between spaces in OSX, where one space has Parallels fullscreen, I would like to be able to swipe further and get to a second Parallels screen *even when I have only one monitor attached to the host machine* - effectively, as far as Windows in the hosted VM is concerned, a second monitor, but one accessible through OSX's Spaces. Is this possible, and if so, how?

This seems to be [possible for VMWare Workstation](https://superuser.com/questions/680841/possible-to-have-multiple-virtual-monitors-for-a-vmware-guest-in-windowed-mode) and possibly VirtualBox, but I can't find anything for Parallels (for that matter, I don't know if the Workstation monitor capability is in VMWare Fusion, either.)

Comment: Have you looked into [Coherence mode](http://download.parallels.com/desktop/v10/docs/en_US/Parallels%20Desktop%20User's%20Guide/32835.htm) ?

Comment: Thanks, but coherence mode puts Windows application on the Mac desktop, doesn't it? I'm seeking virtual screens, not app integration to the host OS. (In fact I keep the VM quite isolated.) I understand why you mention it - that would allow having two Windows apps on two Spaces, I suppose - but it's not adding a second virtual screen / monitor to the VM.

Comment: Aren't there in Parallels any configuration options about many monitors? In other VM software there is possibility to attach few screening devices...

Comment: @pbies That's why I'd like to be able to do it in Parallels. There may be config options, but I've searched and haven't found any.

Comment: Looking for a solution for this too. In VirtualBox I can just increase the number of virtual screens, and I get one window for each screen (which can then be maximized on different physical screens).